# I have been facing an issue with drools when trying to update to 7.73.0.Final

Tags: spring, jboss, drools

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected global [message]

I am not sure why this occurring, I tried to check the drl files, the globals specified and also the kiesession which is configured, but when trying to run on server I face this issue.

Usually the logs should be updated but due to this exceptions no logs are recorded further.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, in your DRL files, you do **NOT** have any line with:

```
global ... message;
```

**but**, in your Java code somewhere, you have a statement ~with:

```
kieSession.setGlobal( "message", ...);
```

hence the error message, `Unexpected global [message]`.

Comment: In my java class :
Map<String, String> messageMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  kieSession.setGlobal("messageMap",messageMap); In my drl file it is mentioned global Map<String, String> messageMap

Comment: The error message per your Question is `Unexpected global [message]` so there is some code somewhere attempting to set a global named `message`. Try to search for all occurrences of `setGlobal` in your code base. If nothing help you should send a reproducer on mailing-list.

Comment: I did set a global named message, but when the version of drools is 7.15.0.Final, I am not getting any issue but when am trying to a version upgrade this exception occurs and am not sure why this exception popping out. As far as I see, everything in the code is fine. Nothing is helping out as I tried all ways. How to send a reproducer on mailing list? @tarilabs